# cross-compiling a Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, 14.10, arm

I am cross-compiling a  Linux kernel  for an embedded ARM system, on Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) desktop. However, I now receive the following errors related to package.

```
khaled@khaled:~/felabs/sysdev/tinysystem/linux-2.6.34$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux- xconfig
  CHECK   qt
*
* Unable to find the QT3 installation. Please make sure that
* the QT3 development package is correctly installed and
* either install pkg-config or set the QTDIR environment
* variable to the correct location.
*
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by 'scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop.
Makefile:460: recipe for target 'xconfig' failed
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Qt GUI framework.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile :

> Before you run `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig` (which is what the
>   next step tells you to do), make sure you have the necessary packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools libqt3-mt-dev # if you plan to use 'make xconfig'
> sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5-dev # if you plan to use 'make menuconfig'
> ```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package qt3-dev-tools

Comment: @JbaliKhaled does the package `libqt4-dev` satisfy `make xconfig`?

Comment: no, libqt4-dev alreday installed but i can't install qt3-apps-dev